# python virtualenv installed packages cannot be imported

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenv

Have a strange problem. I installed a module (cherrypy) into a python venv, but my script can't import it. Is there a problem with the way I'm installing it?

```
(venv)[leon@leon-1 project]$ sudo python server.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 2, in <module>
    import cherrypy
ImportError: No module named cherrypy
(venv)[leon@leon-1 project]$ pip install cherrypy
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): cherrypy in ./venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Comment: You should not run it with sudo. Run directly as `python server.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `sudo python`, you're not running the python interpreter from the virtualenv environment. This is because sudo run commands searching in the system's PATH environment variable, and it won't look in the user's PATH (which is where the virtualenv's interpreter is, usually under `~/.virtualenvs/VIRTUALENV_NAME/bin/python`).

Try running only `python server.py` -- it should work as long as you don't need special permissions (like using a low port number).